# Swift: First TableView Cell overlapping with status bar on viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

I'm currently working on a side menu for my app, everything is working fine, however I've run into a problem the past week that I haven't been able to figure out how to solve.

The problem is that when the table view loads, the cells are pushed up and somewhat overlaps with the status bar, see picture 1 please.

Ideally I'm trying to achieve what picture 2 shows.

From what I've diagnosed, it has something to do with calling the Table View on viewDidLoad, because when I make a selection from the side menu and then dismiss it, the side menu cells are aligned correctly (see picture 2).

I'm not exactly sure what to make of the issue because the cells don't align correctly on initial load up of the app.

[image]
[image]

```
func configureTableView() {
    tableView = UITableView()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    tableView.register(MenuOptionCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    tableView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    tableView.rowHeight = 80


    view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.anchorwithConstant(top: view.topAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingLeading: 0, paddingTrailing: 80, width: 0, height: 0)
}
```

Comment: add top padding 20 and you are ready to go :) .

Answer (score 1):

In the screenshots you shared, there is overlapping at top and bottom both. In iOS 11.0 and onwards `safeAreaLayoutGuide` represents the portion of your view that is unobscured by bars and other content. So adding top and bottom constraints with `topLayoutGuide` and `bottomLayoutGuide` resolves issue of overlapping.

Here is how you can add these constraints in Storyboard/Xib.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use safeAreaLayoutGuide during programmatic constraint. Maybe it solves your problem

```
func configureTableView() {
        tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        tableView.register(MenuOptionCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        tableView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.rowHeight = 80


        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.anchorwithConstant(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingLeading: 0, paddingTrailing: 80, width: 0, height: 0)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use heightForHeaderInSection to increase the margin at the top of the table view. For example:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 100.0 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have following suggestion. Please try this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```